# Determining the equilibrium solution of a direction field for a first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation $dy/dt = f(y)$ and suppose that $y_{1}$ is a critical point, that is,
$f (y_1) = 0$. Show that the constant equilibrium solution $φ(t) = y_1$ is asymptotically stable
if $f' (y_1) < 0$ and unstable if $f' (y_1) > 0$

What i tried,

To have an equilibrium solution, $dy/dt=0$, hence $f(y)=0$, and point $y_{1}$ will be the equilibrium point. While loosely speaking, asymptotically stable means the solution tends to zero,asymptotically unstable means the solution 'moves' away form zero as $t$ tends to infinity. I am able to draw a graph of a direction field and visualize it through a graph. But that is not considered as a rigorous proof. Could anyone please explain. Thanks

Comment: @ ys wong: Use the notion of jacobian matrix evaluated at the equilibrium point.

Comment: Im unsure of how to use the jacobian matrix.

Comment: @ ys wong: You case is: The jacobian matrix is given by $$j=f'(y₁)$$ If $j<0$, then the system is stable and if $j>0$, then the system is unstable.

Comment: @DER This amounts to say that the result is trivial in higher dimension hence it holds in dimension 1. If the OP asks for the dimension 1, presumably they are not allowed to use / are not aware of, the result in higher dimension.

Comment: @Did: The main issue in higher dimension is how to determine the eigenvalues of the jacobian matrix in order to conclud the type of the stability. This method is called: **Studying stability of fixed points by linearisation**.

Comment: @DER Yeah, as I said, every real number is also a matrix of size 1x1. I know that and you know that, the question is whether one should base an answer to the present question on this fact.

Comment: @Did: surely, since the OP discuss the stability of equilibrium points.

Comment: @DER And this where I, and apparently others on the page, disagree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(t)=y(t)-y_1$. (Notice, $g$ measures the distance between a solution curve, $y(t)$, and the fixed point). Then $g'(t)=y'(t)=f(y(t))=f(g(t)+y_1)$

We expand $g'(t)$ using Taylor's theorem.

$g'(t)=f(y_1)+f'(y_1)g(t)+h(g(t))g(t) = f'(y_1)g(t)+h(g(t))g(t)$

As long as we start sufficiently close to $y_1$, we can ensure that $g(t)$ is as small as we like. And since the error term, $h$, goes to zero with $g$, we can ensure that $k_1g(t)<g'(t)<k_2g(t)$ for some pair of constants $k_1$ and $k_2$ that have the same sign as $f'(y_1)$.

This immediately yields the result $g(0)e^{k_1t}<g(t)<g(0)e^{k_2t}$.

Thus, if $f'(y_1)$ is negative, solutions will tend towards $y_1$, and the distance is approximated by a decaying exponential. When $f'(y_1)$ is positive, the flow is reversed, and the point is unstable.